# SalesForce Qlikview integration

Tags: html, salesforce, integration, qlikview

I'm completely new to SalesForce. Would be really great if somebody would sort of push me in the right direction.

What I need to do is to embed several Qlikview objects into SalesForce page. Ideally it should look like the following: each SalesPerson(any contact essentially) on their tab along with the usual contact details(and other stuff) would have a section containing a simple HTML page with QlikView objects embedded.

I know how to integrate Qlikview objects into web page, so all I need to know is how to add a specially created webpage as a part of a certain tab.

It will be really great if somebody can give me an advice on how to do that.. If anyone can share an experience of integrating Qlikview into SalesForce, it would be awesome.

Thanks a lot.

Igor

Comment: Just in case someone will have the same problem, the following are very helpful links:

http://community.qlikview.com/message/79838#79838

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/salesforce_pages_developers_guide.pdf

Comment: I'm not familar with Salesforce, but I found the following Youtube video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HZ9DGFSo_UI. Maybe this helps to set up your QlikView webpage in Salesforce.

Answer (score 3):

you can use Qlikview Mashups to integrate QlikView objects within the salesforce user interfaces.

Have a look at the following resources:

QlikView Mashups: http://tools.qlikblog.at/QlikView-Mashups

Some step by step information about QlikView & salesforce.com integration (explaining the ticketing mechanism): http://community.qlikview.com/docs/DOC-3730

Hope this helps!

Regards
Stefan